# Jquery scroll to part of page on click working intermittently

Tags: jquery, scroll, tabs

I have some image tabbed content which works great.  However, on small screens the tabs stack on top of each other vertically instead of being aligned horizontally.  THis means on mobiles people wont know to scroll down to see the content.

I am trying to get it working so when the tabs are selected they are auto scrolled down to the top of the tabbed content so that the title of the tabbed content shows at the top of the screen.  I have the following code but it seems to work intermittently.  Does anyone know what Im doing wrong?   (https://jsfiddle.net/v5p625qb)

```
// Tabbed Content
$(".tabbed-content-tab").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".hero-title").offset().top
    });

    $(".tabbed-content").removeClass("show");

    var classIdentifier = this.className.match(/content\d/);

    $(".tabbed-content." + classIdentifier).addClass("show");
});

//$(".tabbed-content-tab").first().click();
$(".tabbed-content.content1").addClass("show");
```

---

```
<div class="tabbed-content-tab button content1 col-sm-2">
<div class="pad-box"><img class="aligncenter" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/75675.png" alt="" />
<strong>Image tab 1</strong></div>
</div>

<div class="tabbed-content-tab button content2 col-sm-2">
<div class="pad-box"><img class="aligncenter" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/7567.png" alt="" />
<strong>Image tab 2</strong></div>
</div>

<div class="tabbed-content-tab button content3 col-sm-2">
<div class="pad-box"><img class="aligncenter" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/36556.png" alt="" />
<strong>Image tab 3</strong></div>
</div>

<div class="tabbed-content-tab button content4 col-sm-2">
<div class="pad-box"><img class="aligncenter" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/3232.png" alt="" />
<strong>image tab 4</strong></div>
</div>

<div class="tabbed-content content1">
  <h2 class="hero-title">tab 1 content</h2>
lorem ipsum
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/5345" width="768" height="432" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

</div>

<div class="tabbed-content content2">
  <h2 class="hero-title">tab 2 content</h2>
lorem ipsum
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/3343" width="768" height="432" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

</div>

<div class="tabbed-content content3">
  <h2 class="hero-title">tab 3 content</h2>
lorem ipsum
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/3343" width="768" height="432" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

</div>


<div class="tabbed-content content4">
  <h2 class="hero-title">tab 4 content</h2>
lorem ipsum
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/3343" width="768" height="432" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated version of [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5p625qb/2/).

I changed this line:

```
scrollTop: $(".hero-title").offset().top
```

to find the `.hero-title` you actually want to scroll to instead of all of them.

Also, the hiding and showing must happen before we read the offset since it's dependent on element visibility.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden
>   elements ...

Your version works consistently when the first tab is selected and you click some tab. This is because `offset` gets the offset of the first element in the set of matched elements and you read the offset before hiding the currently opened tab. When some other tab is open you get `0` as the offset.